# SMTP Text file Attachment problem

Tags: vb6, smtp

I am sending a mail with text attachment from my VB6 application.

I am using Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit in header for text attachment.

Problem is that after downloading file from mail,new lines are not displayed properly in NOTEPAD.

But other applications such as notepad++,wordpad are properly displaying the new lines as they are in the original text file.

Where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you are ending your lines with just a new-line, instead of a carriage-return/new-line pair. The windows standard is that you need cr/nl at the end of each line, while Linux puts only nl. Notepad chokes on lines that end with just nl, but Wordpad figures it out.

Comment: i am using vbcrlf for line ending.

Comment: @ramu: Sounds like it shoots down that theory. My next step would be to look at the files with a hex editor and see if there's something funny about the line-end characters -- you're not really getting a crlf, there's a high bit set, there are other control characters, etc. When you say they are "not displayed properly", how are they displayed?

Comment: I got a square box (which is used to represent unknown character in windows) when i view the file in notepad.I Tested text file attachment with Thunderbird also and got the same problem.But with Gmail it is working fine.When i see the full message source in Gmail they are using Content-Type: text/plain;charset=US-ASCII;CONTENT-TRANSFER-ENCODING:BASE64.Finally that did the trick.